# Unable to add printer because of bad device-uri

Tags: linux, network-printer

I'm trying to add a network printer on Linux (Manjaro Gnome 43), but I cannot get it to work.

I am not able to add a printer via the GUI (`Settings` → `Printers` → `Add Printer`). Although the GUI detects the printer, I do get the error "Failed to add new printer" when I select it and click *Add*.

I had that problem before, but then I usually was able to add the printer via CUPS.

I would go to `localhost:631/admin` and select the detected printer in the *Discovered Network Printers*. But I also get an error in CUPS after going through all the steps.

```
Unable to add printer:

    Bad device-uri "socket://[xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%wlp1s0]".
```

(I replaced the characters with `x`)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Debian Bug report
[#599660 cups: Confusing error message when backend programs are disabled](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=599660):

> If the backend for a particular printer is turned off, adding
> printers of that interface type fail with a confusing error message and
> documentation suggesting fixes is apparently not available.

See
[Configuring the Choice of Backend](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPrintQueues?action=show&redirect=PrintQueuesCUPS#Configuring_the_Choice_of_Backend):

> The cups package provides a
> [debconf](https://manpages.debian.org/man/debconf) method for
> selecting
> [backends](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPrintQueues#deviceuri) that are
> used for printer discovery and connection to the device. It basically
> gives a convenient way of copying the backends that come with CUPS
> between /usr/lib/cups/backend-available/ and /usr/lib/cups/backend/.
> Run
>
> ```
> dpkg-reconfigure cups
> ```
>
> Note that not every backend on the system is managed with this command
> because they are not all in the cups package.

Comment: I also wonder if this [old post](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/3859) relates to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me since Manjaro is not Debian based. There is no `/usr/lib/cups/backend-available/` folder.

Comment: Some adaptations may need to be done to the above for Manjaro, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: there is a `hp` file in `/usr/lib/cups/backend/`, I'm trying to add a HP printer